# Unexpected result of if-else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

This is the subroutine which I encountered:

```
int x=3,y=9;
if(x>=y)
  if(y>0)
     x=x*y;
  else if(x<4)
      x=x-y;
```

I guessed that I would get -6 as the answer. Instead I got 3 as the answer. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Make use of {} for clarity of the code.

Comment: That is why I always prefer `{}`

Comment: @JNL Clarity is not the problem here. Correctness is.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar It was in the direction, where Clarity would make the OP understand the issue which would lead to Correctness.

Answer (score 6):

My advice: always add curly brackets even around 1-line if statements. Of course good indentation can also save you a lot of headache. In this case you are confused by the fact that the `else if` is in fact for the second and not for the first if. So you do an else if to `if(y>0)` not to `if(x>=y)`.

Comment: I also like to use automatic indentation and formatting in an IDE, which tends to make the nesting obvious.

Comment: This practice is so worth that most of coding styles include it as "must follow to".

Comment: I actually consider it not so worth if you know the rules. Indentation on the other hand helps you a lot here.

Answer (score 2):

`X` is not greater or equal to `y`. So there will be never any execution of the nested statements which all belong to your second `if(y>0)`.

If you add braces `{}` to every expression like this, it is a lot easier to read, good practice and helps maintaining code. Always do this even for 1-liners and no nested else or anything.

Have a look at this:

```
int x=3, y=9;
if(x>=y)
{
  if(y>0)
  {
     x=x*y;
  }
  else if(x<4)
  {
      x=x-y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can translate your code like this :

```
int x = 3, y = 9;
if (x >= y)
    if (y > 0)
        x = x * y;
    else if (x < 4)
        x = x - y;
```

So therefore, you never go on the branch : `(x >= y)`

As a good practice, use curly brackets and also try to keep your code properly formatted: 
e.g.

```
    int x = 3, y = 9;
    if (x >= y) {
        if (y > 0) {
            x = x * y;
        }
        else if (x < 4) {
            x = x - y;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the rule that an `else` always belongs to the latest `if` if no other precedence is given through brackets.

In fact, the inner `if` is never reached in your case:

```
if(x>=y)
    if(y>0)
        x=x*y;
    else if(x<4)
        x=x-y;
```

This is what's being evaluated. It is equivalent to:

```
if(x>=y)
{
    if(y>0)
        x=x*y;
    else if(x<4)
        x=x-y;
}
```

As `x` is not `>= y`, none of the calculations is ever executed. If you don't want this, you need to use brackets explicitly.

```
if(x>=y)
{
    if(y>0)
        x=x*y;
}
else if(x<4)
{
    x=x-y;
}
```

//code formatting fixed
//next time, do it consequently :-)

Answer (score 0):

The entire nested conditional is not occurring. The outer conditional evaluates as false, so the inner conditional, both the if and the else, are skipped, leaving x as 3. I agree with the commenters that this is why it's better to have the practice of always using curlybraces to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x>=y)
...
```

is 3 >= 9?

... NO!

That's why.

Comment: You may want to fix your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already explained what's going on here. I'll quote Java Language Specification on an official reason behind this:

[14.9. The if Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) provides a declaration of it-then-else statement

> *IfThenElseStatement*:
>
> if ( *Expression* ) *StatementNoShortIf* else *Statement*

*StatementNoShortIf* is described in [14.5. Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5):

> *StatementNoShortIf*:
>
> *StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement*
>
> *LabeledStatementNoShortIf*
>
> *IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf*
>
> *WhileStatementNoShortIf*
>
> *ForStatementNoShortIf*

So, generally if-then-else statement cannot use regular ("short") if statement as a first parameter. Moreover it cannot use code ending in "short" if like: `while(condition) if(condition2) statement` as a first parameter. This way JLS avoids ambiguity of "hanging" else statement.

Thus, in the code below

```
if(x>=y)
    if(y>0)
        x=x*y;
    else 
        if(x<4)x=x-y;
```

`else` cannot be attributed to the first if statement.